# Images become misaligned compared to div items, despite the same css

Tags: html, css

I have a div .pets with several images and divs within it. The css for class pet is applied to both img and div but the images become misaligned as in the image:
[image: images misalign]
Here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pets">
        <img src="/images/animal1.png" class="pet">
        <img src="/images/animal1.png" class="pet">
        <img src="/images/animal1.png" class="pet">
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
        <div class="pet"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css for pets and pet:

```
.pets {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin-top: 15vh;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
.pet {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width:20vh;
    height:20vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

How can I make the images align the same as the divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have given `display: inline-block;` add `vertical-align` too:

```css
.pet {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width:20vh;
  height:20vh;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The default is `vertical-align: baseline;`. That's the reason.

```css
.pets {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.pet {
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pets">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Pet" class="pet">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Pet" class="pet">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=Pet" class="pet">
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
    <div class="pet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `.pets img` `display: inline-block;`

```
.pets img{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If it doesn't solve your problem then use `vertical-align: middle;` as suggested my Paraveen.